# Boltzmann distribution for conical vessel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

I am to derive an expression for the total number of particles in the infinitely high conical vessel with half angle $\alpha$, each of mass $m$, when the system is in equilibrium at temperature $T$ and is placed in a uniform gravity field with acceleration $g$, by using Boltzmann distribution. I know it's $$n_i=\frac{N}{Z}\exp(-\frac{\epsilon}{kT}).$$
 I assume that the energy of each particle is $mgz$, where $z$ is the direction of height of the cone, and it's zero at its bottom. 
However, I'm unsure how I am to go from this to expression, where $n_0$ is a particle density at $z=0$. 
$$N=2\pi n_0(\tan\alpha)^{2}\left(\frac{mg}{kT}\right)^{3}.$$

Comment: Something seems to be missing. What is $n_0$?

Comment: It's the particle density at $z=0$, I've corrected it now.

Comment: But does that fit dimensionally? Maybe the last term should be the scale height $H= kT/mg$ cubed.